# How to use setAttribute on a form collection in ZF2?

Tags: collections, zend-framework2

I haven't found any documentation for setting field attributes to for Zend Framework 2 form collection. I can set the value of a single input field like this:

`$form->get('title')->setAttribute('value', $value);`

What I can't figure out is how to set the values for a collection.

`$form->get('sample_collection')` returns a Zend\Form\Element\Collection Object

It seems like I need to go one layer deeper and select the specific field so that I can use the `->setAttribute` on it.

Thank you in advance for your help in solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use form collection as an array:

```
$elements = $form->get('sample_collection');
foreach($elements as $element){
    $element->setAttribute('value', $value);
}
```

Comment: I think this gets me closer. It seems I need to get the $element back into the $form object. `$form->add($element);` just duplicates the input fields without the value being added.

Answer (score 2):

I had some real trouble with this, the only way I could actually get access to a fieldset inside a collection was with the following. (If the collection has more then one fieldset you would have to add an if statement inside the foreach loop to get the fieldset you want.)

```
$array = array('keys'=>'values');
$collection = $form->get('name_of_collection');
foreach ($collection as $coll)
{
    $fieldset = $coll;
}

$element = $fieldset->get('name_of_element');
$element->setValueOptions($array);
```

**I expected the following to work, which does not. I am not sure if this is a bug in the Zend framework or if I am doing something wrong.**

```
$collection = $form->get('name_of_collection');
$fieldset = $collection->get('name_of_fieldset');
$element = $fieldset->get('name_of_element');
```

If you just want to access a single element inside a fieldset NOT inside a collection. The following has worked fine for me.

```
$fieldset = $form->get('name_of_fieldset');
$element = $fieldset->get('name_of_element');
$element->setAttribute('id', 'name_of_element');
```

I hope this can be of help to someone.